# Check for MySQL database from cmd with result code?

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

I'm trying to make a query from cmd that return 0 if database exists or any other number (for example 1), if it doesn't.

I make the query in this way:

```
"C:\mysql.exe" --host=localhost --user=root --password=pass --execute="SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DB_Name'"
```

If exists, it returns a table (and a exit code 0); if it doesn't, it returns nothing (and a exit code 0 too)

I use this on a Inno Setup installer like:

```
Exec(
  ExpandConstant('{tmp}\mysql.exe'),
  '--host='+eServer.text+' --user='+eUser.text+' --password='+ePass.text+
  ' --port='+ePort.text+
  ' --execute="SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = '+
  ''''+eDBname.text+''''+'"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode); 

if (ResultCode <> 0) then          
    MsgBox('Error when connecting to server', mbError, MB_OK);
```

So it returns me 0 even if the database doesn't exist.

Comment: What about adding `--database "dbname"` to the arguments?  Untested for the moment, but that *should* fail if the db isn't there, otherwise the query will execute normally.

Comment: It Works, thank you so much, can you put your comment to select as answer?

Comment: I added your response before `--execute` and works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` CLI supports a `--database` argument to set the default database before it runs any `--execute` queries.  Setting this value to a nonexistent database (or one for which the user doesn't have the required access) causes the CLI to exit non-zero, because the specified database can't be set as the default.

Add the option in one of these formats:

```sh
--database "dbname"
--database="dbname"
-D "dbname"
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_database